# Hose left on outside faucet over winter with no nozzle, should I replace the faucet before turning it on?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, outdoor, winterizing

We recently bought a house in which I think the hose was hooked up over the winter. It didn't have a nozzle on the end of it, so there wasn't any pressure in the hose.

The faucet is a Woodford model 17.

I haven't turned it on yet, and i'd have to cut into the basement ceiling to look at the stem to see if it's burst.

Should I be worried about turning it on give there was no nozzle attached over the winter?

(I'm located in the midwest. Which equals very cold winters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of the Woodford Model 17 faucet is to have year around use without bursting. [Per their website](http://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/Wall_Faucet_Pages/Model-17.html):

> The freeze-less Model 17 is designed and intended for year-round residential irrigation purposes regardless of outside temperature. This faucet will not rupture from freezing when the valve is shut off and the hose is removed. The Model 17 contains an integral back-flow protection device which protects up to 125 psi of back-pressure and therefor does not require an add-on vacuum breaker.

Since the hose wasn't capped, this would mean it would drain out of the faucet. I would not be afraid of attempting to utilize it one little bit.

Comment: However the "non freeze" portion relies on it not having a hosed attached to it in winter ("hose must be removed in freezing weather or faucet may freeze and burst"), apparently.  That being said if the hose is "empty" then it shouldn't have caused a problem, I can't imagine?

Answer (score 2):

The question I would ask is, was the shutoff value in the basement off? If the valve in the basement is shutoff it does not matter if the hose had a nozzle or not. I do not know where you are located, but if the temperature is above 45, turn it on slowly and see if it leaks, but if the shutoff valve was turned off, I think you are in good shape.

Comment: Since the shutoff is in the ceiling where's it finished, I'm going to guess it wasn't shutoff. It's warm here in Nebraska right now, 70+. Would it be wise to remove the stem valve assembly from the outside and see if i can shine a light down there and see anything?

Comment: If the shutoff valve has been drywalled over or otherwise covered, I would look at fixing this by cutting a hole in the drywall and adding an "access hatch".